# Are IfcOpeningElements available in Autodesk Forge after conversion from IFC to SVF?

Tags: autodesk-forge, ifc

I followed the [View your models tutorial](https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewmodels). IFC to SVF conversion works reasonably well. However, some essential elements are missing after conversion for construction. According to another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62273342/ifcspace-objects-doesnt-show-up-in-autodesk-forge-viewer) IfcSpaces are ignored but the the [wish is already known to the development team](https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2019/06/15/bim-360-api-known-issues-and-wishes/).

Unfortunately, I could not find any informating regarding openings and SVF. Therefore, are [IfcOpeningElement](https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/RELEASE/IFC4_1/FINAL/HTML/schema/ifcproductextension/lexical/ifcopeningelement.htm)s ignored by conversion as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forge introduced a new feature for translating files with options for spaces and opening elements in the advanced options for the output: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/
Look under 'SVF Output Case 1: Input file type is IFC' for a detailed description.

Example request body with IfcSpace and IfcOpeningElement activated for an IFC file:

```
json_encode([
            'input' => [
                'urn' => 'urlsafe_base64_encoded_urn'
            ],
            'output' => [
                'formats' => [[
                    'type' => 'svf',
                    'views' => ['2d', '3d'],
                    'advanced' => [
                        'conversionMethod' => 'modern', // has to be modern for new options
                        'buildingStoreys' => 'show', // adds IfcBuildingStoreys to model
                        'spaces' => 'show', // adds IfcSpace to model
                        'openingElements' => 'show' // adds IfcOpeningElement to model
                    ]
                ]]
            ]
        ]);
```

Edit: Adds 's' to openingElements according to Petr Broz' comment.

Comment: Note that it should be `openingElements`, not `openingElement`. There's a typo in the documentation that's being fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The Forge Model Derivative service extracts the "common type of geometry" from design files, and rooms/spaces are not in that group apparently. The engineering team keeps adding support for additional extracted data based on the customer demand (for example, there's a [new option for extracting Revit rooms](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-rvt-svf-model-derivative-parameter-generates-additional-content-including-rooms-and-spaces)) so if there are several customers asking for `IfcOpeningElement`s as well, we will look into it.

In the meantime, please note that for any IFC data you're missing on the output of the Model Derivative service, you can always use the Design Automation service with Revit and extract this data yourself.